# Melhor opção para dado único (IP, Cookies, MAC)

Tags: php

Essa pergunta pode ser um pouco genérica, dependendo do ponto de vista, mas tentarei ser o mais especifico possível.

Eu possuo um sistema que soma 1 (+1) nas visitas, quando acessado.
Exemplo:

```
<?php
$mysql->query('UPDATE post SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = 10');
?>
```

Acho que entenderam.
O problema, neste caso, é que cada F5 irá atualizar o número de visita, mesmo que seja do mesmo usuário.

Portanto pensei em algumas soluções:

1. Salvar o IP no banco de dados e comparar antes de inserir
2. Salvar um cookie no navegador e verificar antes de inserir.
3. Salvar o MAC no banco de dados e comparar antes de inserir.

**Quais dessas soluções são melhores?**
Levando em consideração a performance e obviamente a dificuldade de alteração (apagar cache/cookies ou usar navegador anonimo quebra o segundo caso, assim como resetar o modem ou usar proxy quebra o primeiro caso, assim como usar alguns outros proxies ou tor quebra o terceiro caso).

Utilizar todos eles seria uma boa alternativa?

> Vi que para obter o MAC via PHP é quase impossível, entretanto o
>   CloudFlare consegue obter esses dados, por isso listei ele, embora não
>   saiba como fazer de fato.

Comment: Pelo MAC seria a melhor opção...porem acredito que  é muito complicado de se obter, melhor opção seria usar cookie + IP

Comment: O cloudflare não obtem MAC nenhum, assim como o browser não tem acesso a isso. Há outras maneiras de se fazer a identificação, mas normalmente se utiliza um misto de técnicas. Erro sempre tem, mas você tem que saber quais as técnicas para errar "pra mais ou pra menos" e vai decidir isso dependendo dos objetivos da contagem.

Comment: Bem, não sei o que obtém, mas já havia sido banido pelo CloudFlare, em um teste. Mesmo alterando o IP, mudando o navegador, apagando todos os caches/cookies ainda continuava bloqueado. Usando proxy (sim, tanto no HTTP e HTTPS) continuava, usando Tor Browser o bloqueio não existia. No  celular (3G)  funcionava, na minha rede não funcionava, mesmo com outro IP. Talvez bloqueassem todo um bloco de IP, mas acho difícil, pois atingiria muitos usuários. Numa conversa que tive com um administrador de uma exchange, que usava do CloudFlare, pediu para que eu altere-se o MAC Address, o que funcionou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na pergunta não especifica o ambiente, portanto vou considerar que pretende usar no ambiente aberto da web. Nesse caso, como não possui acesso administrativo ao browser do cliente não poderá obter o mac address.

As formas viáveis são uma combinação de cookies e IP, caso não possa controlar pela auttenticação (usuário logado).

A combinação de cookie e IP deve ser bem planejada, por exemplo, um wifi gratuito fornece o mesmo IP para milhares de usuários. Num shopping mall, num parque, estações de trem e metrô, ônibus, etc.

Num edifício residencial ou comercial também podemos ter a mesma situação de IP compartilhado. Portanto, não deve-se pensar que o IP identifica como um usuário único. Mas pode ser usado para determinar se aquele usuário retornou e visitou novamente a página. Para isso combina-se os dados de cookies.

**Cookies**

Os cookies são os mais seguro meio possível e padronizado porque esse mesmo usuário sob o mesmo cookie, pode acessar novamente por outro IP. Por isso, a importância em não depender de um único identificador. Capture também informações do browser como o nome e versão do browser. Dois usuários distintos sob um mesmo IP, muitas vezes tem versões de browsers diferentes. Então assim, mesmo que ambos excluam os cookies, será possível fazer uma filtragem posterior para procurar possíveis duplicatas.

**Algoritmos de filtragem**

Sistemas como Youtube por exemplo, usam algoritmos desse tipo para determinar a quantidade de views. Por isso é comum ver vídeos, que possuem 100 mil views de repente perder e ficar om 80 mil views de um dia para outro. Isso deve-se ao fato de que existe uma filtragem posterior. Muitos desconhecem a pensam que o Youtube está "roubando" views. Mas na verdade o que ocorre é uma filtragem posterior pois o sistema de monetização também não pode "roubar" do anunciante. O Youtube foi meramente um exemplo por ser um serviço muito popular, a fim de dar um exemplo prático. Google analytics e Google adsenses faz o mesmo, porém muito mais avançado.

**Fingerprint**

Continuando o assunto, provavelmente vai ouvir o óbvio de que é fácil remover ou editar os cookies. Todavia, um usuário comum não faz esse tipo de ação. Normalmente são usuários com intuito específico em fazê-lo ou meramente um usuário legítimo que simplesmente apagou o cache do navegador. Há também os casos de usuários com múltiplos dispositivos. Acessa pelo smartphone, tablet e PC. Oficialmente é uma única pessoa, porém fez o acesso de dispositivos diferentes. Nesse ponto entra a lógica do seu modelo de negócios. O seu modelo de negócio é quem vai definir daí para frente como lidar. A partir dos dados do cliente, gerar uma espécie de `fingerprint`, por exemplo.

**Autenticação e bots**

Um meio mais seguro é identificar a pessoa por autenticação/login. Sempre que puder, utilize. Faça com que o usuário se identifique. Isso facilitá muito o trabalho de filtragem.

**Bots!**

Claro que também deve estar atento a bots e definir regras sobre como tratá-los.

**Evercookie!**

Opcionalmente há o controverso uso de `evercookie`. Recomendo não usar tal prática. Mas é interessante saber que existe tal "opção".

**Refresh, tempo de navegação**

Obviamente também deve criar alguma lógica para identificar o tempo de navegação e permanência na página, tal como identificar um "refresh" na página. Isso ajudará a identificar como se deu aquele incremento na quantidade de views. Por isso não salve somente +1 nos views. Salve todo o log sobre como aquele view foi gerado.

Normalmente os algoritmos são complexos e não é viável processá-los em tempo de execução. Apenas deixe que os logs sejam salvos e num ambiente privado execute as filtragens. O lado negativo é o acúmulo de dados. Facilmente o banco de dados chegará a 1GB com facilidade numa semana, dependendo do volume de acessos. É difícil lidar com grande volume de dados quando não possui equipe dedicada e especializada nisso. E a maioria das empresas não dispõe desse "luxo" devido aos custos.

**Reinventar a roda. Custo x Benefício.**

Por fim, tudo depende do modelo de negócios. Alguns podem achar exagero tal implementação e realmente é para sistemas pequenos e sem importância. Normalmente sistemas mal feitos e amadores. Mas para projetos de alto nível é bom criar regras consistentes.

No fim, o que vai conseguir desenvolver é algo semelhante ao que já existe, o Google Analytics. Por isso muitos optam em deixar isso aos cuidados de serviços terceiros como o Google Analytics, o qual obviamente possui grande know how.